# I cant get " Consumer Key " in fitbit app registration

Tags: clientid, fitbit

I have registered my app in [fitbit](https://dev.fitbit.com/) . There I can't see  " Consumer Key " option. But I need the key to include in my passport-fitbit integrated application.

[image]

Comment: Read the deprecated statement on this library. You have to use oauth2 now.  https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-fitbit

Comment: ThankQ.. This is what I want. I am unaware of oauth2. Now I got it.